# What is the difference between scaling ec2 instances using SchedulableContainers vs CapacityProviders

Tags: aws-asg

Schedulable Containers assess if more number of ec2 instances are required to be associated to a cluster by determining the memory and cpu available to schedule new containers.
Capacity Providers assess if more number of ec2 instances are required to be associated to a cluster by determining the memory, cpu, network details available to schedule new containers.

What is the difference between using Schedulable Containers vs Capacity Providers?